Analysis of a `log` file
Is there a tool to help analyze the log files produced by (La)TeX? For example, this type of tool should be able to list all warnings issued.

The answers are for some outdated, but one answer points to texlogsieve which is the right tool for my use case.

See https://ctan.org/topic/log-manip

The command line texlogsieve is the right tool for this kind of situation. It is part of TeX Live.
Here is an example of use.
> texlogsieve main.log
----------------
From file DUMMY:
pg 1: (./main.tex
pg 1: (./main.sty
pg 1: )
pg 1: LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 8.
pg 1: Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
      (relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.
pg 1: LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 10.
pg 1: Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
      (relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.
pg 1: LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 12.
pg 1: Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
      (relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.

After last page:

***********
)

====  Summary:  ====


Here is the whole log file.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.11.9)  13 NOV 2024 15:12
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count196
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count197
\c@sapage=\count198

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2022/10/10 v1.3b Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count199
\c@section=\count266
\c@subsection=\count267
\c@subsubsection=\count268
\c@paragraph=\count269
\c@subparagraph=\count270
\c@figure=\count271
\c@table=\count272
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen141
)
\sa@box=\box52
) (./main.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty
Package: relsize 2013/03/29 ver 4.1
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count273
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box53
)
(./main.aux)
\openout1 = `main.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 8.


LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 8.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <24.88> on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <20.74> on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <17.28> on input line 8.

Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.


LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 10.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.


LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 12.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.


LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 12.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.


Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.



[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./main.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1138 strings out of 473362
 20979 string characters out of 5720984
 405846 words of memory out of 5000000
 24290 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 560811 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,10n,71p,183b,161s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb
></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></u
sr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/
local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 47636 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 33 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 19 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


Ok? Can you please add some more info, like an example of how to use it, what results are etc.? Thank you

That has been done.

Thank you. At ctan the manual suggests a lua run … or is it some preinstalles command line tool?

It is part of TeX Live. I have added this information in my answer.

how could anybody else have answered if the correct answer is one suited to your 'use case' and the question never explained what that was? generally, editors do this or you set your editor up to do it. at least, I assume that's what most people do. (sadly my editor gets it very wrong for arara or arara gets it wrong for vim ....)

@cfr I've just pointed out a simple-to-use command-line tool with effective cleaning.

but you don't explain what 'this situation' is. what does this tool do the others don't? or not do the others do? or does it work more easily with your os or editor or what?

As the texlogsieve author, my opinion is obviously biased :), but I believe it is significantly better than the other available tools in any scenario. The brief description (https://ctan.org/pkg/texlogsieve) at ctan presents the main selling points.

I wrote the small perl script texlogfilter, which is also part of TeX Live. It filters latex output or log file according to some usual warning or error patterns. The result is colorized.
I think it's less evolved than texlogsielve but it can be run during latex compilation with
latex file.tex < /dev/null | texlogfilter

I use it usually to filter the continuous output generated by latexmk -pvc ("preview continuously" mode).
There are some options, for example to mask boxes (underfull/overfull boxe) or references (undefined reference) warnings, add some custom regex pattern or display the full log but with colorization.
Here is the help, displayed with texlogfilter -h:
Usage: texlogfilter [options] file.log

Filter latex engines output or log file. log is latex, pdflatex, lualatex or
xelatex output or log file.

Without input file, standard input is used. Use on latex engine output with:
    latex file.tex < /dev/null | texlogfilter

Options:
 --help                 : print this help and exit
 --version              : print version and exit

 --box                  : show box warnings
 --no-box               : mask box warnings

 --ref                  : show reference/citation warnings
 --no-ref               : mask reference/citation warnings

 --info                 : show latex info messages
 --no-info              : mask latex info messages

 --filename             : print current file name
 --no-filename          : do not print current file name
 --files-ext=string     : regex pattern used to match files extension (default: tex|sty|cls|bib|fd|bst|bbx|cbx|def|clo)

 --skips                : indicate skipped lines
 --no-skips             : mask skipped lines
 --skip-marker=string   : marker used to indicate skipped lines (defaut: ...)

 --add-filter=string    : add user filter pattern (as perl regular expression)

 --full-log             : show full log (don't filter - only colorize latex engine output)

 --errors-color=string
 --warnings-color=string
 --infos-color=string
 --skips-color=string
 --user-color=string    : colors used for errors, warnings, informations and skipped lines

and the output, when used on the same file as in projetmbc answer:
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>
Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
Document Class: article 2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 8.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 10.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 12.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input line 12.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.
Package relsize Warning: Font size 29.85591pt is too large.
(relsize)                Using 24.88pt instead on input line 12.
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01>

Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 47636 bytes).

Found 24 warning(s)

